# How to convert a csv or excel file to sql input array in Angular?

Tags: excel, angular, csv, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a way to convert csv or excel file to array of value which I can concatenate with the insert statement for sql query.
The database I'm using is redshift.

this is something i want to to achieve:

- csv file : "value",,134,"domain@mail.co.in"
- ```
         "rocky","xyz",,"domain@mail.com"
  ```

- output: ("value",NULL,134,"domain@mail.co.in"),("rocky", "xyz",NULL,"domain@mail.com")

***is it possible in Angular?***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Angular functionality at all in this task. Maybe this lib helps you: https://github.com/shakhal/csv2sql